# Overwriting key values on a JSON file

Tags: python, json, dictionary

What would be the python code to alphabetize the whitelist values in the json file, without altering the formatting?  Some combination of json.loads(), sorted(), and json.dumps()?

If I use sorted() on the whitelist, I would have a list without \n for each item, to maintain the formatting in the text file.

```
{
  "query": "python",
  "desired_count": 10,
  "batch_limit": 10,
  "optional": {
    "tld": "",
    "lang": "",
    "safe": "",
    "country": ""
  },
  "whitelist": [
    "google-analytics.com",
    "w3.org",
    "jquery.com",
    "jsdelivr.net",
    "polyfill.io",
    "recaptcha.net",
    "youtube-nocookie.com",
    "youtube.com",
    "ytimg.com",
    "vimeo.com",
    "vimeocdn.com",
    "hearstapps.com",
    "highcharts.com",
    "paypal.com",
    "paypalobjects.com",
    "creativecommons.org",
    "licensebuttons.net"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about `without altering the formatting`, when your JSON object is declared as `obj`, is this script of `obj['whitelist'] = sorted(obj['whitelist'])` the direction you expect? https://trinket.io/python/5df3bb62f4

Comment: What I meant, is formatting in the json file, where each item is on its own line.  So if I just use sorted() for the list, I would have a list without \n for each item.  I updated the post to better describe the question.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. I noticed that your question had been resolved. I'm glad for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below. Using indent with json.dumps will keep to your formatting :

```
import json
with open('C:\\Users\\dell\\Desktop\\test.json', 'r') as read_file:
    jsondict = json.load(read_file)
    
# Sorting the whitelist item
jsondict["whitelist"].sort()
    
with open("C:\\Users\\dell\\Desktop\\test1.json", "w") as write_file:
    json.dump(jsondict, write_file, indent=2)  # encode dict into JSON
```